# how to make proper php form validation

Tags: php, validation

I have an issue I hope you can help me with.  I have created a contact form with all the fields validated and a captcha and am still getting loads of spam and blank submissions from it.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I can do to make the form less vulnerable to Spam and black entries

```
 <form method="post" action="submit.php" data-abide id="cont-form">
 <div data-abide-error class="alert callout" style="display: none;">
 <p><i class="fi-alert"></i> There are some errors in your form.</p></div>
  <input form="cont-form" type="text" name="yourname" placeholder="Your      Name" required>
  <input form="cont-form" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" required>
    <span class="form-error">Your Email Address Is Invalid</span>
    <input form="cont-form" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number" required >
    <span class="form-error">Please Enter A Valid Phone Number</span>
    <input form="cont-form" type="text" name="hear" placeholder="How Did You Hear About Us?" required>
    <textarea form="cont-form" placeholder="Your Message" type="text" name="message" required></textarea>

<label>What's 13+14 = </label><input form="cont-form" name="answer" type="text" />

    <button  type="submit" name="submit" value="submit message" class="button" data-text="submit message"><span>submit message</span></button>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </form>

$answer = 27;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
 if ($answer != $_POST['answer'] ) {
$hasError = true;
}else{
 $content = '';
if($_POST["yourname"]){
$yourname = $_POST["yourname"];
}

if($_POST["email"]){
 $email=$_POST["email"];  
}

if($_POST["phone"]){
$phone=$_POST["phone"];   
}

if(!empty($_POST["type"])){
$type=$_POST["type"];
}
 if($_POST["hear"]){
  $hear=$_POST["hear"];
 }
if($_POST["message"]){
$message=$_POST["message"];
}
}
$content = "Name : " . $yourname . "<br>";
$content .= "Email : " . $email . "<br>";
$content .= "Phone : " . $phone . "<br>";
$content .= "Message : ". $message ."<br>";
$content .= "How Did You Hear? : ". $hear ."<br>";

 if($hasError != true){
 mail($sendToEmail,$subject,$content,$senderEmailId);
header("Location:thankyou.php");
exit();
}
else
{ 
?>
<script language="javascript">
 alert("Sorry,An Error Occurred.Please Try After Some Time");
  window.history.back(); 
 </script>
 <?php
 }
```

Comment: "What's 13+14" is not really a captcha it's just a simple math problem as text. Use some common and modern captcha like [recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)

Comment: It would work pretty well if you display it as an image, and if you change randomly the numbers, and eventually the operator ... and add some noise to the picture ... or just stick with one of the captchas in the market

Comment: OP, you haven't marked any answer on any of your question as *accepted*. Please do accept answers if they solved your problem. This way, your question will be marked as answered. Also consider giving upvotes to helpful answers. If you continue to not accept answers, people will be less and less likely to help you in the future. Also, if you found your own solution to one of your questions, remember that you can *answer your own question*, then mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**You should just look that up with a search engine, really - plenty of advice out there.**

Generally speaking, there are many methods and you will most likely want to combine several to get satisfying results. Most will be an annoyance to your users, the best example being Captchas. Whatever you decide for, try to make it as user-friendly as possible.

One of my favorite techniques are **honeypots**, which means that you include hidden form fields. Some of them you leave empty, some you pre-fill with data. In your backend (PHP), you then test if the fields still hold the expected values (being empty or holding the exact values you put into them). Most bots will just blindly fill any available fields. To make this method more efficient, include fields that are hidden through `type="hidden"` plus at least one that is hidden through CSS. Also, fill one of them with JavaScript as many bots do not execute JavaScript and will hence fail to fill these fields with the (expected) value.

Another thing you could do is define a dictionary with **badwords** and filter out submitted data that contains these words. However, you might accidentally filter out actual legit user data, so be careful when choosing the dictionary.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, before sending an email of the data you need to first verify it's validity to avoid blank entries. 
if the submit button is pushed then
   verify the validity of the submitted data(important fields are not empty, valid email...etc)
   if all the submitted data is valid, then 
      send the data by email, or any other action you wanna make
   else (if some data are not valid)
   show the errors and not to submit anything.

Here's what i see missing in your code:
1- if (isset($_POST['submit'])) before starting to process your form, it simply tells the code not to start processing unless the button submit is pushed.
2- To avoid blank entries you just need to test, that every entry submitted is not blank using if (!empty($_POST['variable_name'])).
3- also you need to check the validity of the email addresses submitted using a built in php function like : $filter_var($_POST['email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL]) which returns true if the email submitted is valid.

also you may need to put some constraints on what type of characters are allowed to be submitted in the name field etc using a preg_match php function.

Here's a link that might be helpful http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp